# Update combobox based on another combobox through query

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have several combo boxes (CB) populating from my access database. They all pull from the same table and use the same hidden primary key from the table. When I select a value from one of the CB's I would like to have the others updated with the associated value based on the matching primary key.

Is this possible?

I've been trying to use variations of the following for a while now with no success:

```
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "SELECT gsr_id FROM task WHERE task_wid = " & Me.cboTask.Column(0)
Me.cboGSRTask.Section = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

Debug.Print "SELECT gsr_id FROM task WHERE task_wid = " & Me.cboTask.Column(0)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I get the following error: Type mismatch
I've tried converting data types with str, int, variant but have not had any success.

Comment: Yes, it is a combo box. I want to update all combo boxes whenever one of them is changed. The value they get updated to should come from the same record on the database (using primary key). I may be going about it incorrectly but that is what I am hoping to accomplish.

Comment: That was just the last one I tried. I looked at a few others prior to that and was not getting it to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open a recordset, you need to read a value from it, you can't use the recordset as value.
I guess what you are looking for is:

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim RS As Recordset

strSQL = "SELECT gsr_id FROM task WHERE task_wid = " & Me.cboTask.Column(0)
Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

' This assumes that gsr_id is the bound column of cboGSRTask
Me.cboGSRTask = RS!gsr_id
RS.Close
```

Or instead all of the above, using DLookup() :

```
Me.cboGSRTask = DLookup("gsr_id", "task", "task_wid = " & Me.cboTask.Column(0))
```

Or it might be even easier to add `gsr_id` to the row source of cboTask (as a column with width = 0) and use that column to assign to cboGSRTask.

Comment: I played around with a few solutions you provided and felt that the DLookup was most useful for my needs. Really appreciate your answer, thank you!